# Populating HTML with JSON data using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I am trying to dynamically create a list of applicants in my HTML. I have a list of applicant saved in JSON format that I am reading in. I have an HTML template of the applicant "tile" that I read in, populate and then append to the page for each applicant.

My template:

```
<div>
   <div class="name"></div>
   <div class="age"></div>
   <div class="gender"></div>
   <div class="email"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i></div>
</div>
```

My JSON data:

```
{
  "applicants" : [
    {
      "name" : "John Smith",
      "email" : "email@gmail.com",
      "gender" : "Male",
      "age" : "22"
    }
  ]
}
```

My jQuery:

```
 $.get("applicants.json", function(json) {
     json.applicants.forEach(function(applicant) {
         var newApplicant = $(templates).find("#applicant").html();

         $(newApplicant).find(".name").append(applicant.name);
         $(newApplicant).find(".email").append(applicant.email);
         $(newApplicant).find(".gender").append(applicant.gender);
         $(newApplicant).find(".age").append(applicant.age);

         $(newApplicant).appendTo(".applicant-list");
     });
 });
```

After running this code, I am just getting the template back without the JSON information.

I have tried placing a `console.log()` after appending `applicant.name` but there is still no change to `newApplicant`.

Something else I tried was `console.log($(newApplicant).find(".name").append(applicant.name).html());` which showed me that the `.name` is being populated but those changes are not persisting.

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: try to change setting data from `append` to `text` when you apply json

Comment: @MysterX That didn't work. I tried that but still getting the same thing. That also won't work with age because it will remove the icon.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am not sure if `forEach` would be a right one. You can use jQuery's `$.each` function to loop in an array with `this` being referred as the current iterated object:

```
$.each(json.applicants, function () {

  var newApplicant = $("body").find("#applicant > div").clone();

  newApplicant.find(".name").append(this.name);
  newApplicant.find(".email").append(this.email);
  newApplicant.find(".gender").append(this.gender);
  newApplicant.find(".age").append(this.age);

  $(newApplicant).appendTo(".applicant-list");
});
```

**Snippet**

```js
$(function () {
  json = {
    "applicants" : [
      {
        "name" : "Nicholas Robinson",
        "email" : "ntrpilot@gmail.com",
        "gender" : "Male",
        "age" : "22"
      }
    ]
  };

  $.each(json.applicants, function () {

    var newApplicant = $("body").find("#applicant > div").clone();

    newApplicant.find(".name").append(this.name);
    newApplicant.find(".email").append(this.email);
    newApplicant.find(".gender").append(this.gender);
    newApplicant.find(".age").append(this.age);

    $(newApplicant).appendTo(".applicant-list");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<div id="applicant">
  <div>
    <div class="name"></div>
    <div class="age"></div>
    <div class="gender"></div>
    <div class="email"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i></div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="applicant-list"></div>
```

Comment: The problem isn't with the iteration hey. If I print `applicant.name` I do get the expected value.

Comment: @NicholasRobinson See how I have handled `newApplicant`.

Comment: @PraveenKumar: Perhaps you could add an explanation about what's wrong with the code in the question and how you've corrected that, instead of just providing code that supposedly works better?

Comment: @NicholasRobinson I have added an explanation and a working fiddle, if it helps.

Comment: @PraveenKumar I think that this answer doesn't account the fact that the json is in an external file and starts from parsing an object that in the question was clearly not in there.

Comment: @Andre.IDK I was more concerned about the `$.each` and not getting the JSON. That was just a ****ing demo for this snippet, and if you fail to understand that, you are not a good developer.

Comment: What else would you require to remove the downvote @Andre.IDK?

Comment: @PraveenKumar Generally speaking I agree with you but calm down, since your answer was chosen I said what I said just for the sake of completeness, nothing personal at all, I think the main goal of this website is not to show off ourselves but try to help each other and a complete answer is the best way to do it. Anyway I can't remove the down vote until you edit the answer. And speaking of downvotes, does anyone think that as soon as I downvoted and commented this answer I got downvoted in other completely different and unrelated questions?

Comment: @Andre.IDK I have edited my answer... I am not sure about the other issue but well, I have been receiving hit and run downvotes a lot... Hurts me.

Comment: @PraveenKumar Yeah, it's a real struggle.. Anyway, down vote removed. Have a nice day!

Answer (score 1):

In the question you omitted two HTML elements that instead you mention in the jQuery code, so according to the latter, and correct me if I'm wrong, the HTML should look like that

```
<div class="applicant-list">
    <div class="applicant">
        <div class="name"></div>
        <div class="age"></div>
        <div class="gender"></div>
        <div class="email"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Then, in the jQuery you should either use your `$.get()` function and then parse or use instead `$.getJSON()`

```
$.getJSON("applicants.json", function(json) {
    json.applicants.forEach(function(applicant) {
        var newApplicant = $('body').find(".applicant").clone();

        $(newApplicant).find(".name").append(applicant.name);
        $(newApplicant).find(".email").append(applicant.email);
        $(newApplicant).find(".gender").append(applicant.gender);
        $(newApplicant).find(".age").append(applicant.age);
        $(newApplicant).appendTo(".applicant-list");
    });
});
```